# Git checkout can't auto-complete with bash

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete

I'm using ubuntu with bash. When I typed `git checkout` then press `tab`, I expected it would show a list of branches, but I got:

```
git checkout
bash: eval: line 345: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: eval: line 346: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I googled it but found nothing. And bash even doesn't tell me where is the `line 345`. Anyone knows what's wrong?

**EDIT**:

When I `set -x` to bash and then `git checkout [tab]`, it outputs:

```
+++ case "$c$2" in
+++ printf '%s
' 'feature/capybara '
+++ for c in '$1'
+++ case "$c$2" in
+++ printf '%s
' 'feature/chinese-search '
+++ for c in '$1'
+++ case "$c$2" in
+++ printf '%s
' 'feature/comment_validation '
+++ for c in '$1'
+++ case "$c$2" in
+++ printf '%s
' 'feature/comments '
```

...and so on. No error. But I still can't use autocompletion normally.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: the line is a reference to git-completion.bash.  find that on your system, and see what line 345 looks like.

Comment: have you tried a new install of git (if that is an option.  i don't know if this is your home box or a work machine)?  if not, you can always check out the version of git that you currently have, and replace the git-completion.bash and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Is the filename correct? I tried `sudo find / -name "git-completion"` but found nothing.

Comment: On my gentoo system the file is at `/usr/share/bash-completion/git`, and is installed by the git package. See if you can find it on your ubuntu (maybe with `dpkg -L git`).

Comment: You could try getting a fresh copy of the bash completion file: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? In 11.10 I see that lines 345 and 346 of `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` are comments.

Comment: my lines 345 and 365 are `#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
`

Answer (score 1):

Try `set -x` in bash:

```
-x   Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
```

This should show you what code fails, as it will show what kind of work bash completion does in the background.

Comment: when I `set -x`, the auto-complete mysteriously works well?! (see my OP edit)